# Analytics library for iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, analytics

I want to integrate analytics into my iOS app to collect statistics about my users.

So far I found these two services:

- http://www.localytics.com
- http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/

I want a library that's easy to implement. Are there any more out there and what is your experience? What can you recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) in several apps.  Quite happy with it.  Once the initial setup is done, it's quite easy to log and record metrics about pretty much anything within your app.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [heatma.ps](https://heatma.ps) to get insides on how people iteract with your applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [UXCam](http://uxcam.com) very useful. It has very easy integration steps and provides user and mobile data you need. It lets you watch playback videos of users using your app and has rule based recording and analytics to filter out unusual session.